# OpenCTI search cases based on phone number

Tags: case, opencti

In OpenCTI currently I am able to find the contacts associated with a phone number using searchandscreenpop method and get contacts as response.

Is it possible to get list of Cases associated with a phone number.

When I tried, I didn't get the case objects in response.

Also tried entering the phone number in search bar manually, that too didn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the  softphonelayout settings in setup menu under callcenters. Edit the softphonelayout and then add the entity you want to return in list there